# erorr occured when I use timediff on python

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python

I wrote this sql code in my database and it worked

```
INSERT INTO moni (sn, dgw, tgw, delay_gw_server) VALUES ('2020060002', '2020-07-05', '11:12:17', timediff(NOW(), (cast(concat(dgw, ' ', tgw) as datetime))))
```

can I use this code into python code?

```
date = ‘2020-07-07’
time = ‘17:17:17’
concat = ‘%s %s’ %(date, time)
dt = datetime.datetime.strptime(concat, ‘%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S’)
diff = (datetime.datetime.now() - dt)

mycursor = mydb.cursor()
    sql = "INSERT INTO moni (sn, dgw, tgw, delay_gw_server) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s)"
    val = (sn, date, time, diff)
    
    mycursor.execute(sql, val)
    mydb.commit()
```

or this code ?

```
date = ‘2020-07-07’
time = ‘17:17:17’
concat = ‘%s %s’ %(date, time)
dt = datetime.datetime.strptime(concat, ‘%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S’)

mycursor = mydb.cursor()
    sql = "INSERT INTO moni (sn, dgw, tgw, delay_gw_server) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s)"
    val = (sn, date, time, timediff(NOW(), dt))
    
    mycursor.execute(sql, val)
    mydb.commit()
```

Comment: *timediff(NOW(), dt)* - in the last code this expression will be calculated in python code then (if not fail) the value will be inserted into the query as a parameter value.

Comment: thankyou so much, i’ll try to run that code